# Boxplot function for variable by split per country

Tags: r

I want to use boxplot.stats on variable by a country split.

Something like `boxplot.stats(data$Variable[Country==French])$out` does not work. Is there a way to handle it in query or I need to slice my dataframe first to countries?

So far what I am doing is:

```
FRA <- subset(data, Country=="French")
boxplot.stats(FRA$Variable1)$out
```

for each country. It gets problematic if there are more than few countries so solving it by one line would be awesome

@duckmayr, @Dario - data is presented that way, it goes all the way to hundreds of thousands. I have multiple countries, few scale variables and want to point out outlier values for each of them

[image]

Comment: $out gives outliers from the boxplot.stats function I want to get outliers for each country this way

Comment: If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) you could make it easier for others to find and test an answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide example data, I'll demonstrate with the `mtcars` dataset.
We'll look at a boxplot of `mpg`, grouping by number of cylinders:

```r
res <- boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
```

[image]

We've saved the results to the object `res` so we can inspect the outliers.
How can we do that?
Consider the following from `help("boxplot")`:

> Value
>
> List with the following components:
>
> [some text omitted]
>
> out      the values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes of the whiskers.
> group      a vector of the same length as out whose elements indicate to which group the outlier belongs.
> names      a vector of names for the groups.

The `out` element of `res` contains the outliers, while the `group` element says which group each of the outliers came from, and the `names` element gives the names of the groups.
So, we can see each outlier and which group it came from via the following:

```r
cbind(outlier_value = res$out, outlier_group = res$names[res$group])
#      outlier_value outlier_group
# [1,] "10.4"        "8"          
# [2,] "10.4"        "8"
```

In other words, `res$out` gives the outliers, and if we subset `res$names` by the group indices in `res$group`, we get the group names corresponding to each element of `res$out`.

Comment: I've came up with the sample dataset, however your code seem to be working brilliantly! 

Could you please explain how you came up with that? It works brilliant but where I can get more in-depth about that, how does it work underneath as the code is not so clear for me what R does

Comment: @rainbowthug I've added some additional explanation. Don't forget to [click on the check mark if this solves your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!